# jQuery resize function not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage with a large header image at the top of the page that occupies the entire view width and height. I found a very helpful snippet online that avoided the strange resizing issue that happens on mobile when the url bar disappears. Before including the code below, the header image would increase in size when the url bar disappeared because the view height would become larger. The code works perfectly except the problem persists on iOS Chrome app. Any help here is greatly appreciated

I have decided to take a new approach to solving this problem since the URL bar height on safari and chrome vary. This would cause unwanted complications and it would be difficult to have the adjustment work perfectly on both browsers. The new approach I am taking is that when viewing the webpage on tablet or mobile, I would like to set the height to the view height on load and have it stay at that height. I have updated the jQuery code below to what I have so far, however it still does not work as expected.

HTML:

```
<div class="intro-bg">
    <div class="intro-bg-item"> 
        <div class="intro-bg-item-image" style="background-image: url(css/images/pb/home-banner.jpg)"></div><!-- /.intro-bg-item-image -->
    </div><!-- /.intro-bg-item -->  
</div><!-- /.intro-bg -->
```

jQuery:

```
if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
var bg = $(".intro-bg-item-image, .intro-bg-item, .intro-bg, .caroufredsel_wrapper");
function resizeBackground() {
    bg.height( $(window).height());
}
$(window).load(resizeBackground);
resizeBackground();
```

}

Comment: Did you check that resizeBackground() gets called in ios after resize (eg. put an alert inside the function).

Comment: Are you opposed to handling this with CSS? From your description, this sounds like a CSS issue. Run a media query to change background-size or to change the supplied image. Although of course either strategy could work.

Comment: @rob maybe I could use jquery to determine the view height on page load on mobile and then set the height to be that height as opposed to 100vh which would chnage when the url bar disappears?

Comment: @yezzz confirmed if I put an alert into the function it displays on iOS after resize.

Comment: Indeed may be a css issue. Found some js on the page which adds `is-ios` class to the body for iphone/ipad/ipod user agents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to tried media queries? It would be liter than having JS listen for the browser resize and you could target specific browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Have tried many solutions with media queries with no success. Thanks for the suggestion though.